# Convert $\partial t$ into $\partial x$ in a heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

We shall consider functions $h=h(t, x):[0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow(0, \infty)$ which are $2 \pi$-periodic with respect to $x$, belong to $C^{\infty}([0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R})$ and satisfy the $1 \mathrm{D}$ heat equation
$$
h_t-h_{xx}=0, \quad \text { in }(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} .
$$
and the Boltzmann’s entropy is introduced:
$$
H(t)=\int_0^{2\pi} h(t,x)\log(h(t,x))\mathrm{d}x.$$
The first task is to show that $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}t}\leqslant 0$.
My solution is as follow:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}t}&=
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^{2\pi} h(t,x)\log(h(t,x))\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[h(t,x)\log(h(t,x))]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}[h_t(\log(h)+1)]\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{2\pi}[h_{xx}(\log(h)+1)]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(\log(h)+1)\mathrm{d}h_x
=(\log h+1)h_x\bigg|_0^{2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{h^2_x}{h}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{h^2_x}{h}\mathrm{d}x\leqslant 0.
\end{align*}
But the formal answer is like:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d t} H(t) & =\int_0^{2 \pi} \partial_t[h(t, x) \log (h(t, x))] d x \\
& =\int_0^{2 \pi} \partial_x[(\log (h(t, x))+1) \partial h(t, x)]-\frac{\left|\partial_x h(t, x)\right|^2}{h(t, x)} d x
\end{aligned}
Can anyone see how to convert $\partial t$ into $\partial x$?

Comment: I think they are doing what you did.